# ¿Cómo evitar valores duplicados dentro de un GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando ahora, ya con esta sentencia logro que no repita los **`p.id_cliente`**,

Lo que ahora trato de hacer es que dentro del **`GROUP_CONCAT`** no se repitan el **`em.razon_social`** ya qu hay casos que se repiten tres o cuatro veces eso tiene que ver con la cantidad de veces la cual **`p.id_cliente`** se repite

```
SELECT p.id_cliente, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(em.razon_social) AS empresa 
FROM tbl_proyecto p, 
     tbl_empresa em 
WHERE p.id_empresa = em.id 
GROUP BY p.id_cliente
```

Comment: Dentro del GROUP concat agrega un distinct y nos comentas

Comment: Era eso lo que faltaba, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu `GROUP_CONCAT` agrega el uso de [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) para evitar *valores duplicados* sobre la columna deseada:

De la siguiente forma:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT em.razon_social) AS empresa
```